# Best way to give conditional formatting to handsontable when data is more than 5k

Tags: javascript, performance, handsontable

We have data around 5000 to 10000.

Now in that data, we have to give conditional styling to row, column or some cell.

I try to give conditional formatting, as they have suggested in [this link](https://docs.handsontable.com/0.23.0/demo-conditional-formatting.html).

But we are facing performance issues. So how to give styling where there is bigger data.

I tried to use hot.getCell() function, but that function is giving null value.

Answer (score 0):

As, you need to detect the limit of data, obviously you need to check this on either, key strokes (worst), other events, getCell().

getCell() works flawlessly if your code is rendering properly.

You can modify cellProperties in cells option function in configuration object. For example you can call function in cells method, that will check properties which you want to add to your configuration. This should work.

The option mentioned above is called cells not cell. Other than that it's true :)